# modlib3.c:21:9: error: invalid use of incomplete typedef 'DIR {aka struct _dirstream}

Tags: c, linux, typedef, ls, opendir

The problem is I need to use LD_PRELOAD to modify the opendir() function in that is part of the ls command to restrict the opening of directories when the target path is not within the /home directory. The error I am getting is with the return line that says:
return((*original_opendir)(_name));
In that the original_opendir is bolded and it says error: invalid use of incomplete typedef 'DIR{aka struct _distream)'

I have attached my code below. Please let me know if you have any ideas I would really appreciate it![enter image description here][1]

The file name was called modlib3.c and I compiled it with this when I got the errors:
//gcc -o modlib3.so -shared -fPIC -D_GNU_SOURCE modlib3.c -ldl

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


DIR *opendir(const char *_name) {
  DIR       (*original_opendir)(const char *);
  *(void **)(&original_opendir) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "*opendir");  
  if (strcmp(_name, "/home") <0 || strcmp(_name, "/home")>0){
    syslog(LOG_EMERG, "Cannot open! ");
    exit(1);
  }
  return((*original_opendir)(_name));
 }
```

Comment: You are trying to reinvent `chroot`?

Comment: Essentially I want the ls command to not open anything that isn't from the home directory

Comment: As a start, you should use `realpath(3)` to resolve symlinks and relative pathnames.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed some of the problems in the code, please check the differences carefully

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

DIR *opendir(const char *_name) {
  DIR      *(*original_opendir)(const char *);
  *(void **)(&original_opendir) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "opendir");
  if (strncmp(_name, "/home", 5)!=0) {
    syslog(LOG_EMERG, "Cannot open!");
    exit(1);
  }
  return((*original_opendir)(_name));
 }
```